# How to crawl/index the links on a single page: Google Search Appliance

Tags: google-search-appliance

Am new to the GSA and also don't have full admin access to the system so have to forward requests through to ICT Services to have changes made to our crawls and collections.

I hope someone can help with this question:

I have a single web page which has a list of links to about 180 documents (most of which are stored in the same subdirectory /docs/ which contains some 2400 documents). The rest are scattered across the site in a number of other subdirectories ie /finance/, /hr/ etc

At the moment all that happens is that I either get the single webpage indexed and none of the 180 links. Or I get the 1 page plus ALL of the 2400 documents in the /docs/ subdirectory.

I want to be able to just crawl/index this page and the 180 links and create a separate collection

Is there a simple way to do this?

Regards
Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of configuring the URL pattern under start urls and follow pattern,
   configure the complete url. Get the 180 urls + 1 single web page url and put all 181 urls under start urls and follow pattern.By configuring complete urls, we could avoid GSA being crawling the other urls in the application as we are not keeping any common url pattern under follow urls.
2. Create a new collection and place all 180 doc urls + single web page
   url (or generic pattern matching 181 urls) in that collection under "**Include Content Matching the Following Patterns**".

I assume that you do not want to index other 2400 documents on GSA.
Hope it helps.

Regards,

Mohan.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use a robots.txt file to disallow crawling of the other pages you don't want.  This would be a lot of work if you have to enumerate all of them though.

Your best bet is to see if there is some common URL pattern you can use to specify only the 180 pages you do want.  For example, are the pages you do want all PDFs, and the other files you do not want are all some other type?  If you can find something that is common for all the pages you want that isn't true for the other pages, you can use that to formulate a pattern (maybe using regex) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a meta and url feed for this.

It will allow you to control whether the GSA follows links in your 180 pages if you fed them in or whether you index your list page if you just feed that. You do this by specifying noindex or nofollow.

You'll still need to have your follow and crawl patterns and collections set up correctly but it's the easiest way to control what gets indexed.

You don't necessarily need to write code for this either, you can use curl and hand craft the xml.

The documentation is pretty good and easy to follow. [Feeds Protocol Developers Guide](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/)